# GIT - Pushing from fork to upstream master

Tags: git

So I have forked a repo.

I would normally do fork, branch then create pull request from my fork.

Can I work in master I have locally then push to my fork and then push the master in my fork straight to the upstream master with

```
git push upstream master
```

Before I do this I would pull from upstream to make sure I was up to date

My origin is called upstream as well

Can I push master in my fork to master at upstream with

```
git push upstream master
```

Comment: Just an FYI, in git branching is not forking. They have distinct and different meanings.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what the question is...

Comment: If the question is: "can I push a local branch to multiple upstreams?", then the answer is yes.  If that's not the question, you may need to be a little more concrete about what exactly you're trying to push, and where to.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand yout question correctly, then you don't need and should not work to `master` directly: this is the purpose of the branches. Commit your modifications in to branches (one branch per purpose, even if it's contains a single commit), then send a pull request for each one. The owner of the original repository can fast forward your branches (to merge without merge commit) but it's his/her decision, not yours.

---

BTW it's funny that you can technically make a pull request on `master` but it's not a recomended way.